# Naming of Haskell Modules

Tags: haskell

I am doing the 99 Haskell problems: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems

I can name modules something like "Nine.hs" and at the top of that file have

```
module Nine where
...
```

but in the interest of brevity I would like to write "9.hs" and have

```
module 9 where
...
```

unfortunately this gives me a parse error. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, module names may not begin with a digit. You could name it something like `P9`, though.

Answer (score 11):

From [chapter 5 of the Haskell 2010 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-980005):

> A module name ... is a sequence of one or more identifiers beginning with capital letters, separated by dots, with no intervening spaces.

So no, it's not possible in standard Haskell.

I am not aware of any language extension that would allow you to do what you want.